# How to calculate column in table with search on javascript

Tags: javascript

I have Table :

```
----------------
| Name | Price |
----------------
| A    | 1,200 |
| B    | 500   |
| C    | 3,000 |
----------------
| sum     4,700|
----------------
```

If I search " A " I get Table as :

```
----------------
| Name | Price |
----------------
|  A   | 1,200 |
----------------
| sum    1,200 |
----------------
```

How to calculate column with search table and sum change.

Comment: Please share your html

Comment: Please show your html

Comment: Please show your javascript, see [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).